# robot jumps when spawn

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when ever robot is spawn into gazebo it jumps there is the video below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h_KuQWqSG-fN56pFwcY_P6YahA0ftZVe/view?usp=sharing

edit

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="mark" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  
  <xacro:property name="pi" value="3.1415926535897931" />

  <!-- Includes -->
    <xacro:include filename="$(find mark_description)/urdf/mark_base.urdf.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="$(find mark_description)/urdf/mark_caster.urdf.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="$(find mark_description)/urdf/mark_wheel.urdf.xacro"/>

    <!-- Differential Drive Plugin -->
 <gazebo>
    <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>10.0</updateRate> 
        <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
        <publishWheelTF>true</publishWheelTF>
        <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
        <wheelAcceleration>1</wheelAcceleration>
        <leftJoint>left_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
        <rightJoint>right_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
        <wheelSeparation>0.33</wheelSeparation>
        <wheelDiameter>0.17</wheelDiameter>
        <wheelTorque>20</wheelTorque>
        <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
        <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
        <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

    <!-- Base -->
    <xacro:mark_base prefix="base"/>

                       
    <!-- Left Wheel -->
    <xacro:mark_wheel prefix="left_wheel" 
                        joint_x="-0.099185" 
                        joint_y="0.23646" 
                        joint_z="-0.059645" 
                        joint_roll="0.0" 
                        joint_pitch="0.0" 
                        joint_yaw="0.0"  
                                            r="-1.57075"
                        parent_link="base_link" />
  
    <!-- Right Wheel     -->                    
    <xacro:mark_wheel prefix="right_wheel" 
                        joint_x="-0.099185" 
                        joint_y="-0.23646" 
                        joint_z="-0.059645" 
                        joint_roll="0.0" 
                        joint_pitch="0.0" 
                        joint_yaw="0.0"  
                                            r="1.57075"
                        parent_link="base_link" />

    <!-- Caster -->  
    <xacro:mark_caster prefix="front_caster" 
                        
                         x="0.2347" 
                         y="0.0" 
                         z="-0.083329" 
                         roll="0.0"
                         pitch="0.0" 
                         yaw="0.0"  
                         parent_link="base_link" />
</robot>
```

caster wheel xacro

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:macro name="mark_caster" params="prefix x y z roll pitch yaw parent_link">

        <link name="${prefix}_base_link">
            <inertial>
                <mass value="0.01" />
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
                <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-6"  iyz="0.0" izz="1e-6" />
            </inertial>
            
            <visual>
                <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://mark_description/mesh/caster/un.dae"/>
                </geometry>

                <material name="Grey"/>
            </visual>

            <collision>
                <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>

                <geometry>
                     <mesh filename="package://mark_description/mesh/caster/un.dae"/>               
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        
        <gazebo reference="${prefix}_base_link">
            <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
            <mu1>0.0</mu1>
            <mu2>0.0</mu2>
            <kp>1000000.0</kp>
            <kd>100.0</kd>
            <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
            <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>        
        </gazebo>
        
        <joint name="${prefix}_base_joint" type="fixed">
            <parent link="${parent_link}"/>
            <child link="${prefix}_base_link"/>
            <origin rpy="${roll} ${pitch} ${yaw}" xyz="${x} ${y} ${z}"/>
            <axis xyz="0 0 0"/>
        </joint>
                
                        
        <link name="${prefix}_rotate_link">
            <inertial>
                <mass value="0.01" />
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
                <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-6" />
            </inertial>
            
            <visual>
                <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://mark_description/mesh/caster/caster_rot.stl"/>    
                </geometry>

                <material name="Grey"/>
            </visual>
            
            <collision>
                <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://mark_description/mesh/caster/caster_rot.stl"/>    
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        
        <gazebo reference="${prefix}_rotate_link">
            <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
            <mu1>0.0</mu1>
            <mu2>0.0</mu2>
            <kp>1000000.0</kp>
            <kd>100.0</kd>
            <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
            <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>            
        </gazebo>
                
        <joint name="${prefix}_base_rotate_joint" type="continuous">
            <parent link="${prefix}_base_link"/>
            <child link="${prefix}_rotate_link"/>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.01"/>
            <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        </joint>                        
                                    
        <link name="${prefix}_wheel_link">
            <inertial>
                <mass value="0.01" />
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
                <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-6" />
            </inertial>
            
            <visual>
                <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://mark_description/mesh/caster/caster_wheel.dae"/>          
                </geometry>
                <material name="Yellow"/>
            </visual>
            
            <collision>
                <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <mesh filename="package://mark_description/mesh/caster/caster_wheel.dae"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>    
        </link>
        
        <gazebo reference="${prefix}_wheel_link">
            <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
            <mu1>0.0</mu1>
            <mu2>0.0</mu2>
            <kp>1000000.0</kp>
            <kd>100.0</kd>
            <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
            <maxVel>1.0</maxVel>
        </gazebo>
        
        <joint name="${prefix}_rotate_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
            <parent link="${prefix}_rotate_link"/>
            <child link="${prefix}_wheel_link"/>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.013 0 -0.03"/>
            <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
        </joint>    

    </xacro:macro>  
</robot>
```

it all started when i entered caster_rotate_link

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379065/robot-jumps-when-spawn/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2021-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-05-27**:
Not 100% sure this would work, but have you tried setting the inertia values *ixx*, *iyy*, and *izz* to a non-zero value for the links `caster_rotate_link` and `caster_base_link`?

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-05-27**:
Yes I tried same thing happens

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-05-27**:
Like @abhishek47kashyap said, the inertias should probably be non-zero.  In addition, I've seen this kind of behavior when there's overlapping geometry (inherent collisions).  Such situations can cause the solver to "explode" the model.  Since you're using meshes, I can't tell if there is a collision, so you'll have to do a close inspection of the model before starting the simulation.  Remember that `visual` and `collision` elements aren't necessarily the same.

On a side note, the inconsistent formatting of your URDF makes it difficult to read.  Others may be more encouraged to answer if the information you provide is easier to assimilate :).

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-05-27**:
@tryan If you want I can send you my urdf file it will be a huge help

**Comment by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on 2021-05-27**:
What does inherent collision means

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-05-28**:\

> I can send you my urdf file

If you have extra info, please edit your post to add/link it.

> What does inherent collision means

I just mean that the robot may be defined in such a way that parts of it collide with each other.  For example, if a wheel happens to be placed such that it intersects part of the chassis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From personal experience, this is most likely due to overlaps between the environment geometry and the initially spawned robot geometry (so, you basically have collisions present). You can spawn the robot at a higher `z` value to see if that fixes things.

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2021-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1